# Flow network with source S and sink T, How to find maximal flow between any 2 vertex?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

Given a flow network with a source s and a sink t. For every two nodes u, v, assume that the capacity from u to v is the same as the capacity from v to u. Given two vertices x, y, design a polynomial-time algorithm to find one single path from x to y that you can send as much flow as possible along that path.
Briefly justify the correctness of your algorithm and analyze the running time.

thanks a lot

Comment: Webber my first answer wasn't exactly what you were looking for, so I just edited my answer, please check and let me know if you didnot understand any part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is called maximal flow algorithm and it has multiple [solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions), and all of them are polynomial.

You could use [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm),because it is easy to understand and as you can see wiki page have all the things you want about this algorithm.

**EDIT :** the answer that I provided before, didnot give you the single path, instead it gives you the maximum flow.

For finding the single path, you just have to find *bottle neck* in every path between x and y. By bottle neck I mean the lowest capacity edge in path, because the capacity of your path is capacity of that edge.

For finding the lowest capacity in each path you could simply start removing edges from graph from lowest capacity to highest, and with removing every edge from graph just check if x and y are connected or not. First edge that make x and y disconnected is the edge that you want and its capacity is the capacity that you want. Because every path between x and y are either have this edge or an edge with lower capacity.

the time complexity of algorithm :

1. sorting edges : O(E log E).
2. remove every edge till you find the desired edge : O(E).
3. check connectivity in step two : O(V + E) (check it with [Strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) algorithm)

so the complexity of algorithm is : O(E log E) + O(E V + E<sup>2</sup>) = **O(E V + E<sup>2</sup>)**

Comment: The problem is not exactly the maximum flow problem. In this problem we have to send a flow along exactly one path while in the maximum flow problem we can send it by multiple paths.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I just edited my answer and post the answer regarding to this question.